# How to enure the latest JS code is loaded by Task Pane add-in?

Tags: macos, office-addins, office-js

I am running into an issue with my Task Pane add-in when running it in desktop Excel 2016 on the Mac (OSX).  I have deployed the first version of the add-in to a web server and successfully inserted a reference to the add-in's manifest into an Excel workbook and can see it working on the client box (the Mac).  Then I made a few changes to some JavaScript code in my add-in's "foo.js" and then deployed those changes to the web server.  Now when I open the workbook I do not see the behavior I expect from the new version of foo.js, rather the old behavior is seen.

What I have tried:

1. On the same Mac, loaded foo.js directly from the web app in Safari. I can see the changes in the js code that I expect to be in the second version.
2. Cleared the Safari cache (I suspected that this would not work based on #1 - Safari does not appear to share a cache with Excel but worth a shot) - did not change anything.
3. Poked around under ~/Library/Containers/com.microsoft.Excel trying to find a cache - deleted ~/Library/Containers/com.microsoft.Excel/Data/Library/Caches/com.microsoft.Excel - no help.
4. Use the Reload menu item from the Task Pane's context menu (looks like [i] on the Mac) - no difference: still seeing old foo.js.

How can I get Excel/the embedded web browser component to retrieve the new foo.js?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your HTML is refreshing correctly, disable caching entirely on your page with content="nocache" (further details at [Using <meta> tags to turn off caching in all browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1341089/using-meta-tags-to-turn-off-caching-in-all-browsers)).

Also, just to make sure, clearing the cache: ⌥+⌘+E > Privacy > Remove All Website Data

Comment: To add to what Michael Saunders wrote: there are a variety of web cache-busting techniques, such as http://madskristensen.net/post/cache-busting-in-aspnet.  Versioning your assets is probably the easiest.

Comment: @MichaelZlatkovsky  & Michael S: thanks for the replies. The server side solutions you suggest seem fine for the longer term (although I am not sure if the meta/no-cache tag in an html page transitively applies to JS files downloaded via that page). However during development I'd like to have a client side solution ("Remove All Website Data" did not work). There are no proxies or other server web caches between my client and the web server, and with Safari I can get the updated resource, so I surmise that there is a different client side cache being used. Hoping to hear of a way to clear it.